# Reading int value from text file, and using value to alter file contents to separate text file.(java)

Tags: java, file, loops, text

So I'm trying to read input from a text file, store it into variables, and then output an altered version of that text onto a different file using a variable from the file. I'm using Filereader, Scanner, and Printwriter to do this. 
I have to store the last line (which is a number) from this text document and use that number to multiply the body of text onto a different file without including the number.

So the text is:
[Original file text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zdWV.png)

And the output is SUPPOSED to be:
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr4EO.png)

I'm able to retrieve the number and store it into my multiplier variable and retrieve the text into my string BUT it's stored as a single line if I check inside the console:
[how the text is stored seen through console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNOvQ.png)

so it outputs like this on the new file:
[undesired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yat85.png)

I'm pretty new to Java, forgive me if there are any questions I can't answer that could help solve any issues with my code.

I've tried adding `+"\n"` to the file output line but no dice. I've also tried adding it to *words += keys.nextLine() `+"\n"`*, and it separates the lines in the CONSOLE but not the file itself, unfortunately. Am I at least on the right track?

Here's my code:

```
public class fileRead {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    String words = "" ; //Stores the text from file
    int multiplier = 1; // Stores the number

    FileReader fr = new FileReader("hw3q3.txt");
    Scanner keys = new Scanner(fr);

    //while loop returns true if there is another line of text will repeat and store lines of text until the last line which is an int
    while(keys.hasNextLine())
        if (keys.hasNextInt()) { //validation that will read lines until it see's an integer and stores that number
            multiplier = keys.nextInt(); //Stores the number from text
        } else {
            words += keys.nextLine();//Stores the lines of text
            keys.nextLine();
        }
    keys.close();
    PrintWriter outputFile =  new PrintWriter("hw3q3x3.txt");
    for(int i = 1; i <= multiplier; i++) {
        outputFile.println(words);

    }
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.println("Data Written");
    System.out.println(multiplier);//just to see if it read the number
    System.out.println(words); //too see what was stored in 'words'
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the if-statement below:

```
words += keys.nextLine(); //Stores the lines of text
if(words.endsWith(words.substring(words.lastIndexOf(" ")+1))) { //detect last word in sentence 
        words += '\n'; //after last word, append newline
}

...

for(int i = 1; i <= multiplier; i++) {
        outputFile.print(words); //change this to print instead of println
}
```

Basically, after the last word in the sentence within the file we want to append a newline character to start writing the next sentence from new line.

The above if-statement detects the end of the sentence by determining the last word within the `words` String, and then appending a newline character to the `words` String. This will yield the result that you are expecting.

Breaking down the expression for you:

```
words.substring(words.lastIndexOf(" ")+1)
```

Return the part of the String (`substring`) that is located at the index of the last whitespace in the String plus 1 (`lastIndexOf(" ") + 1`) - i.e. we're getting the word after the last whitespace, so the last word.

Entire while-loop:

```
while(keys.hasNextLine()) {
    if (keys.hasNextInt()) { //validation that will read lines until it see's an integer and stores that number
        multiplier = keys.nextInt(); //Stores the number from text
    } else {
        words += keys.nextLine();//Stores the lines of text
        if(words.endsWith(words.substring(words.lastIndexOf(" ")+1))) {
            words += '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding. So nesting that if statement inside the else statement will look at the last word of the line/string? or the text of the file? Also, i didn't realize that "keys.nextLine();" statement was in there. That's was placed there by accident and hope that doesnt influence your answer. edit: ok nevermind, I understand what you're explaining, thank you!

Comment: It will look at the last word of the words String, which is basically a single line in your file. E.g. for "a brown frog leaps over lazy dog" it will return last word "dog", next sentence "the tail is long and brown" it will return "brown". No, it doesn't influence my answer, you get the idea :) I have edited answer and your question to delete that typo.